# Ways to integrate app in GMail

Tags: gmail, google-apps

Is there any way to integrate an app into GMail (with like a custom button next to the send button which will perform a request to a specific url) without an Firefox / Chrome addon? So an application really integrated in GMail?

I was wondering as I would like to do the following;

1. Allow a user to click to move a message to a specific (hardcoded) folder
2. Put the message back at the top of their inbox after a API query (from my app). So the Inbox priority filtering should be managable.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at [Gmail Gadgets](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/gadgets_overview).

> Gadgets are custom HTML and JavaScript components that run within an
>   iframe and can be embedded within various web pages. Gmail includes
>   support for embedding gadgets within the web interface, creating
>   content-rich data displays and extending Gmail with additional
>   functionality.

Comment: Is it also possible to put like a specific e-mail on top of the inbox?

Comment: No, contextual gadgets act on the specific data of an email. Sidebar gadgets function to the left in Gmail. There is no way to re-order messages in the Gmail message list with gadgets.